# How to format date to 01-JAN-2021 using java

Tags: java

Let's say I have a date like Fri Jul 16 12:04:35 EAT 2021

I want to change it to 16-JUL-2021. How do I go about it?

Comment: Take a look at `DateTimeFormatter` class documentation here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: *can be in any format* makes this task really tough...

Comment: If it can be in any format, then you can't do anything predictable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("Fri Jul 16 12:04:35 EAT 2021", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy
"));
String newDate = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy")).toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleDateFormat:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
//...
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-LLL-yyyy");
String text = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: Yea ... but `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are legacy classes.  For Java 8 and later, you should be using the `java.time` classes.

Answer (score -1):

```
    String startDateInput = "Fri Jul 16 12:04:35 EAT 2021";
    String date = startDateInput.substring(8, 10) + "-" +  
                  startDateInput.substring(4, 7) + "-"
                  + startDateInput.substring(startDateInput.length() - 4);
```